# How can I tell if a Springs and Struts app is scaling in the iPhone 6 simulator?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have a couple applications built pre-auto-layout (but w/ Springs and Struts to support iPhone 5+) that I'm trying out in the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus simulator and they actually look quite good.  However, I can't tell if the Springs and Struts are actually doing their job so-to-speak or if they're just being scaled.  There must be some obvious thing I'm missing where it says which?  Also, do auto-layout apps just automatically convert when recompiled with the latest SDK for iPhone 6 so they're not just scaling as long as 3X artwork is provided (in the case of 6 Plus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see, if your app runs in scaled mode by outputting the bounds and the native bounds screen of the main screen:

```
println("bounds = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)")
println("nativeBounds = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds)")
```

Without a designated launch images the output of the iPhone 6 Plus Simulator is:

```
bounds = (0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0)
nativeBounds = (0.0,0.0,960.0,1440.0)
```

The native bounds are 3 times the scaled bounds. This is the reason behind the @3x display.scale.

In case of the **iPhone 6 Plus** `nativeScale` also helps:

```
println("main screen native scale = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale)")
println("main screen scale = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)")
```

`nativeScale` will always be `3.0`. `scale` will be `2.0` if the simulator does scaling.

To get a comprehensive understanding of the new resolutions see this great blog entry: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Answer (score 1):

Use a different launch image for iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus and all the rest.
If you see a specific lunch image you know your app is not scaled and that it is running in the device's native resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to tell was to go home and see if the status bar text was smaller than it was in my app. A smaller home screen status bar implies it is being scaled. If the status bar text is the same size within your app in the iPhone 6 sim as it is on the home screen of the simulator, then it is using your springs/struts or autolayout instead of scaling